# disable query syntax assistance?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just upgraded to PHPMyAdmin 4.7.7 and there are some good improvements, but I need to figure out how to disable the "query assistance".

The coding I do involves a lot of complex queries, and the syntax checking built into this version makes the UI unusably slow when a 20 line query is displayed.

Is there a way to disable the javascript syntax assistance?

Comment: It's also VERY annoying because it doesn't recognize all legal MySQL - I get errors when I use a case statement....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## disbale for a single page

When you're on the SQL query box page, click on the `settings gear` in the upper right corner and disable `CodeMirror` and `Linter`. After saving, the features should be disabled and you should see a normal text box for the queries.

## disable globally

If you want to disbale it *forever*, you need to change/extend your `config.inc.php` configuration file. The option you are looking for is `$cfg['CodemirrorEnable']`. Just set this to `false` and this option is dissabled globally. As `Linter` depends on `CodeMirror` this will disable both. You need to log-in again to phpMyAdmin to take effect.

Comment: This works for a single query, but it resets the next time i load the page.

Comment: Updated my answer, @whiteatom

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is in the settings.. my browser seems to have something cached. In the main settings for PHPmyAdmin under SQL Queries, CodeMirror can be disabled.